# How to update startpoint to replace merge commit

Tags: git, git-svn, branching-and-merging

We'd like to convert an svn repository to git. Now I'd like to do some cleanup on a converted branch:

```
A1-A2-A3--A6-A7-----A11-A12-An
    \      \            /
     `------B1-B2---B25´
```

B1 is a merge commit to import the changes A3 to A7 into branch B. The better way might be to start from A7 and remove the merge commit B1.

```
A1--A6-A7-A8-A9----A12-An
         \         /
          `B2--B25´
```

I've tried a rebase on branch B to A but the result is already the same.

**Update**
As a missundertsanding of upstream there is no tracked remote branch on A.
(svn branches and tags has been removed).

*I've updated the title also*

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right path. Try the following to rebase your changes from the B branch to the tip of the A branch:

```
git checkout A
git pull
git checkout B
git pull
git rebase A
<fix conflicts>
git push -f
```

Comment: Thanks for your anser. It seems that I've missunderstood the woridng of `upstream`. In my first understanding it might be another word for parent local branch. I'll clarify this in the question part.

Answer (score 0):

A tecnical point : if you redact the history, new commits will be created (they will have new hashes, and if your currennt history is already shared with other developers, you will have to tell them to force update their repo).

I will describe a way to transform :

```
# this :
A1-A2-A3--A6-A7-----A11-A12-An
    \      \            /
     `------B1-B2---B25´

# into this :
A1--A6-A7-A8-A9---A11-A'12-A'n
         \           /
          `B'2--B'25´
```

Commits on the `B` branch will be new commits, as well as commits on the `A` branch, starting from the `merge in B` commit.

---

For starters, I would suggest to work on temporary branches :

```
# create branch 'wipB' on commit B25 and switch to this new branch :
git checkout -b wipB B25
```

1. If you want to replay `B2, ..., B25` on top of `A7`, you can use the
   `git rebase --onto <new_base> <upstream> <branch>`
   variant of `git rebase` ([doc here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)) :

   ```
   # note the `B1` : the commit mentionned as <upstream> is ommitted
   git rebase --onto A7 B1 wipB
   ```
2. to recreate the merge commit `A12` :

   ```
   # start a new "A" branch from A11 :
   git checkout -b wipA A11

   # merge the new "B" branch :
   git merge wipB

   # once merge is resolved, you can compare with the original A12 to see
   # if this new merge commit has all the content you expect :
   git difftool -d wipA A12
   ```
3. to replay `A13, .., An` on top of `A'12` :

   ```
   git rebase --onto wipA A12 An
   ```